# Parse.com Notify Clients Without Client Polling

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a turn-based game with Unity and I am using Parse Unity SDK as the backend.

So far the only way to refresh the client is to poll the server for changes. This works, but we are thinking of saving bandwidth.

I have done some research over my side and so far here's what I have in mind but I was looking out for more options and seeing if anyone has a better idea on how we will go about doing this:

1. Use Parse push notification with cloud code, client register with parse and in afterSave hook in parse cloud code, do a push notification. However I have read push notification can take up to an unacceptable 20 mins delay at times.
2. Adopt another external service, eg: pubnub, all clients register with pubnub. In afterSave hook in parse cloud code call a restful api in pubnub to broadcast to all registered client that parse contains new data, client will poll the server only when they receive such event from pubnub. However, we really want to see if we can use just parse alone to do something like this.

Any suggestions and comments is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thought is **perfectly correct.  It's simply not a job for Parse.  Use PubNub** or perhaps Firebase or similar - your guess is 100% correct.

Note that a very similar question is often asked on here: "Can I make a chat app using Parse and push notifications."  The answer is just "no", it's silly.  Of course you need a real-time connection. In the "old days", you'd just write a permanently connected client-server system.  (Not unlike, simply when you telnet to a server.)  Today, just as you say, use PubNub or a similar service. (Ultimately you could use SmartFox or the like - but PubNub is the answer here.)

{Regarding doing it using repeated polling, that's just silly, forget it!}

If you're just starting out, nice work on guessing the way to do it in your point (2)

- BTW There are any number of articles around on "combining Parse and PubNub", for, exactly the sort of reason you point out.  For [example](https://parse.com/questions/combine-parse-with-pubnub-pusher-or-similar-for-real-time-messaging) an early note on that when folks were just working it out.
- Further, it seems to me really strange that the owners of Parse, ie FB, have not yet "simply" incorported PubNub, Pusher, etc -like functionality, inside of, Parse. It's quite mysterious why they don't do this.
- Finally note that you mention PubNub (which is amazing). It's possible Pusher https://pusher.com is "even more amazing" for the example problem you describe - unfortunately I've not had a chance to try it.

Comment: I have looked into Pusher before that but it seems like they do not have an official Unity SDK so I threw it to the back of my list. We are afraid that it might suddenly stop working when the APIs gets updated / Unity gets updated after we have integrated it to our system and we are left dangling in the open.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with Pusher, use PubNub, Firebase or another service. Or indeed ... as in the "old days" write your own persistent server. The answer to your question is, as you suspect, "don't poll".