# Slow queries to a Parse database

Tags: database, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

We have a web player game communicating to a Parse database. There is a significant number of slow queries sent to the database and each one of these, eventually, freezes the game at the loading screen.

Is there anything at all that can be done here?

Comment: One thing to consider is that you possibly shouldn't be using Parse at all.  Recent QA on that .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32224211/294884